# Style the <Form.Select> dropdown menu in React-Bootstrap

Tags: css, react-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu using react-bootstrap as in the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-buck-lyqd22)

I would like to style the dropdown menu to look similar to the picture below
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-do-i-style-a-select-dropdown-with-only-css , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: You should search on the web before asking here!! or try to find on youtube there a lot of tutorials. Take a look at this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IXFoH5XAwBg)

Comment: you can try this. https://codepen.io/CrystalRcodes/pen/BamPEJo and play with it

Comment: @Tenz, are you using react-bootstrap? Because in your post I see a usual select element

Comment: @IgorGonak yes, I use react-boostrap. I am trying to change the popup window. I tried others' suggestions but still cannot get it as expected.

Comment: What exactly is on your image? Is "test1" currently selected? Why it is not in the list? Why is there vertical space around "value3"?  Is the green border around select input AND the dropdown?

Comment: @IgorGonak Test 3 is highlighted when it is hovered. Test 1 is the first option in the select menu. When clicking into the dropdown menu, it shows the list "test 1, test 2, test 3..." Hover over any of the options that will highlight it (as of test 3 is highlighted when hovered".

Comment: @IgorGonak I have the CodeSandbox up and you can see what I mean. I just want to know how to style/ change the dropdown menu color, border, and highlighted color instead of the original color https://codesandbox.io/s/great-buck-lyqd22

Comment: no, I can't see any related code in your sandbox. it's just the standard one when you create it, without any additional code. What do you mean by "highlighted" color? active?hover?

Comment: vee and Crystal provided you with useful answers. What are you missing? We won't just right 100% code that you wish. You have to read, understand and do it yourself. Especially when you ask general questions and not specific one.
Please read the accepted answer in this post carefully and make your conclusions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)